# Reflection geting value from method argument annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Sample code:

```
public interface TestClass {

    @AnnoTest
    public Object getTestObject( @AnnoTestArg("id") Integer postId );

}
```

How can i get value from `@AnnoTestArg` annotation ? I know how to check is argument annotated but, i can't check annotation value.

That's my code:

```
public void build(...) {
    Annotation[][] anno = pm.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();

    for( Annotation a : anno[argNumber] ) {
        if( a.equals(AnnoTestArg.class) ) {
            // value ?
        }
    }


    return connector;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Annotation` is the superinterface of all annotation types. Assuming your `AnnoTestArg` annotation is something like

```
@Target(value = ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface AnnoTestArg {
    String value();
}
```

you can just cast the `Annotation` value to `AnnoTestArg` and invoke the appropriate method

```
for (Annotation a : anno[0]) {
    if (a instanceof AnnoTestArg) {
        AnnoTestArg arg = (AnnoTestArg) a;
        System.out.println(arg.value());
    }
}
```